# Convert part of CSV file to html

Tags: html, excel, vba, csv

I've been tasked to create a webshop.
I've figured out how the webshop functions work and to ease up my workflow. I'm trying to automate the conversion of a part of the CSV files into HTML tables.

So I need to convert a list of specifications of a product into one long string of a complete HTML table.
At the moment I succeeded into creating an example of the final result

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rxv13.png)

I'm trying to find a way to create a program that asks for a range of data, then converts it row by row and adds it to each respective description.

I have programmed in Visual Basic, but primarily .NET and C#. Never used VBA.

Comment: Could you add a better picture of your data/work?

Comment: So you'll read the input csv file using C# (and output an HTML) ? Does [these](https://duckduckgo.com/?t=ffab&q=table+to+html&ia=web) work?

Comment: I'm not sure what the best solution would be. 
Create a windows form using C# or create something for excel.

Comment: Bit difficult with what you have shown. You can however, with VBA, automate saving a csv as html btw. It is an inbuilt save option. This includes saving ranges as html table. I am happy to write something up if you would like as I have done this before, just need to know a bit more about whether this is something you would use.